# clustering a SUPER large data set

Tags: database, r, matlab, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I am working on a project as a part of my class curriculum . Its a project for Advanced Database Management Systems and it goes like this.

1)Download large number of images (1000,000) --> Done

2)Cluster them according to their visual Similarity

a)Find histogram of each image --> Done

b)Now group (cluster) images according to their visual similarity.

Now, I am having a problem with part 2b. Here is what I did:

A)I found the histogram of each image using matlab and now have represented it using a 1D vector(16 X 16 X 16) . There are 4096 values in a single vector.

B)I generated an ARFF file. It has the following format. There are 1000,000 histograms (1 for each image..thus 1000,000 rows in the file) and 4097 values in each row (image_name + 4096 double values to represent the histogram)

C)The file size is 34 GB. THE BIG QUESTION: HOW THE HECK DO I CLUSTER THIS FILE???

I tried using WEKA and other online tools. But they all hang. Weka gets stuck and says "Reading a file".

I have a RAM of 8 GB on my desktop. I don't have access to any cluster as such. I tried googling but couldn't find anything helpful about clustering large datasets. How do I cluster these entries?

This is what I thought:

**Approach One:**

Should I do it in batches of 50,000 or something? Like, cluster the first 50,000 entries. Find as many possible clusters call them k1,k2,k3... kn.

Then pick the the next 50,000 and allot them to one of these clusters and so on? Will this be an accurate representation of all the images. Because, clustering is done only on the basis of first 50,000 images!!

**Approach Two:**

Do the above process using random 50,000 entries?

Any one any inputs?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

Any clustering algorithm can be used.

Comment: I think this questions is too vague for stackoverflow as it stands right now, but I don't see why you have cluster all of them. Just do a sub-sample and apply it the rest. Also, I'm sure you can perform some dimension reduction on the images themselves which will not only improve your memory issues but probably improve performace by removing some unwanted noise.

Comment: Please explain why the question is vague. Even if I do all the above pre processing, I am pretty sure that the size of the file cannot be reduced to less than 10 GB. Having said that even a 10 GB file size is a big size!. And no, i did not know about sub sampling, hence the reason to post the question here.

Comment: Because this isn't a programming question. There is no code or data for us to work with and at a high level things are unclear. For example you don't even list what clustering algorithms you want to use.

Comment: A)There is no need for it to be a programming question. 
B)There is no need for code.
C)This is more of an algorithmic question. Its a challenge to cluster large data set
D)Any clustering algo can be used

Comment: @Nikhil this is a Q&A site about programming, so people here are expecting programming questions and enjoy solving coding problems. For algorithmic questions there is [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning cross validated. up voted your comment

Comment: I think this is your problem right here: ` 4096 double values to represent the histogram` If you want to summarize your images you need to do it more compactly than in 4096 double values. Either you can use a histogram with less bins, or you can define some properties of the histogram and calculate them from these 4096 values.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Thanks, looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weka isn't your best too for this. I found [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) to be much more powerful (and faster) when it comes to clustering. The largest I've ran are ~3 million objects in 128 dimensions.

However, note that at this size and dimensionality, your main concern should be **result quality**.

If you run e.g. k-means, the result will essentially be random because of you using 4096 histogram bins (way too much, in particular with squared euclidean distance).

To get good result, you need to step back an *think* some more.

1. What makes two images similar. How can you measure similarity? *Verify* your similarity measure first.
2. Which algorithm can *use* this notion of similarity? *Verify* the algorithm on a small data set first.
3. How can the algorithm be scaled up using indexing or parallelism?

In my experience, color histograms worked best on the range of 8 bins for hue x 3 bins for saturation x 3 bins for brightness. Beyond that, the binning is too fine grained. Plus *it destroys your similarity measure*.

If you run k-means, you gain absolutely nothing by adding more data. It searches for statistical *means* and adding more data won't find a different mean, but just some more digits of precision. So you may just as well use a sample of just 10k or 100k pictures, and you will get virtually the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Running it several times for independent sets of pictures results in different cluster clusters which are difficult to merge. Thus two similar images are placed in different clusters. I would run the clustering algorithm for a random set of images (as large as possible) and use these cluster definitions to sort all other images.

Alternative: Reduce the compexity of your data, e.g. to a histogram of 1024 double values.

Comment: OK ..a question here: If, using random samples, I get 'x' clusters, I will need to find a single histogram which represents each of those 'x' clusters.. right? And then, take the remaining images. Compare their histogram to these 'x' histograms and then place the images in those clusters to which their histograms have the closest match. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: I don't know how your clusters are defined, but if they are defined via nearest distance to the center this is an approbate method.

Comment: I am allowed to use any clustering algorithm. However, the project description suggested that AP clustering should be used. What in that case?